# Is it possible to customize the keyboard from UITextField?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uitextfield

I have a view controller where my keyboard is on screen for the entire time. Because of this, I was hoping to make it's height a bit smaller, and it's also a game app so I was hoping to make the keyboard look more gamey.

How should I approach this? Can I customize the keyboard this much in code? Should I try to make my own keyboard with more than 20 custom buttons to form a keyboard?

Comment: You may be able to subclass UITextField and modify it appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Garrett is correct, you cannot customize the standard iOS keyboards, there is however a way to provide a custom view in its place.

`UITextField` has a property on it called [inputView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#inputView)

That will allow you to provide the view you want while still keeping the nicety of using the textfield to become and resign first responder.

Since you stated the keyboard is always open in the app, I am assuming you are only created/setting the UITextField once.

So, in `viewDidLoad` bring up the keyboard so it stays on screen and set it's inputView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIView *customKeyboardView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomKeyboard" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
    self.myTextField.inputView = customKeyboardView;

    [self.myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Why set the `inputView` in this delegate method? Set it in `viewDidLoad` or when you create the `UITextField`. Otherwise you create and set the input view every time the text field is about to become the first responder.

Comment: @rmaddy that was just an example. I agree OP would be better off setting this up somewhere like `viewDidLoad`. Just trying to show how to use UITextField's inputView

Comment: It's always best to answer questions with code that shows best practices. Answers like this get copy and pasted by people who don't know better and people learn bad habits.

Comment: @bmende self.view does not respond properly in this way. Calling [self.view becomeFirstResponder] will not bring up the keyboard.

Comment: @DanFairaizl That's not any better (as a general example). You still end up creating the input view every time the text field becomes the first responder. Create and assign the input view in `viewDidLoad`. There is no need for the delegate method at all in this case.

Comment: @rmaddy, I updated the example again to show the general case. Normally I would argue that since OP's app will have the keyboard open all the time, only one UITextField instance is needed. And if we are just arguing about whether to use the textfield's delegate or not, it's just a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't like you to customize their keyboard, it's part of what makes their OS distinctive. I had the same problem once when I wanted to add extra buttons to the keypad number input. If you want to tweak the keyboard, you're going to have to create your own custom view.